# Confidence intervals on maximum likelihoods of observed data

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I observed 400 episodes of nursing care in a hospital. I tracked the movement of the nurses between 5 rooms $A-E$.  The maximum likelihood of them moving from room $i\rightarrow j$ is given by:

\begin{equation}
P_{ij}=\displaystyle \dfrac{\text{# of times from room $i\rightarrow j$}}{\displaystyle \text{Total # of transitions to any room}}\end{equation}

- Is there a way of defining a confidence interval on this maximum
  likelihood estimate $P_{ij}$?
- And for all maximum likelihood
  estimates of all possible room combinations?

**Reference**:

I have come across a reference: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4131v1.pdf
This suggests that for n observations $X_i$, the empirical maximum likelihood estimate $\hat P_{ij}$  minus the actual transition probability $P_{ij}$ would tend to a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and matrix of variance-covariances $\Sigma$.

$$\sqrt{n}|\hat{P_{ij}}-P_{ij}|\sim N(0,\Sigma)\quad \text{as}\quad n\rightarrow \infty$$

How to I calculate $\Sigma$ from my observed data? And how does this relate to confidence intervals?

Comment: It would be a confidencce interval for the unobservable proportion, based on the observable MLE.

Comment: . . . also, one should call this a maximum likelihood estimate of that proportion.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that for me at all?

Answer (score 1):

One could probably think about the nature of the *dependence* among the various random variables that would have been observed, but for now I'll do something simpler:

You have $n$ independent Bernoulli trials; in this case $n=400$.  You have $x$ successes; in this case, $x$ is the numerator in the fraction.  So the number of successes is binomially distributed with an unobservable parameter $p$.  Theory tells us the expected value of the number of successes is $400p$ and the variance of the number of successes is $400p(1-p)$.  That means the expected proportion of successes is $p$ and the variance of the proportion is $p(1-p)/400$.  So we can cite the central limit theorem and we have an approximately normal distribution; thus about a $0.95$ chance of being between $-1.96$ and $+1.96$.  We use $x/400$ as an estimate of $p$.  Our $95\%$ confidence interval therefore has endpoints
$$
\frac{x}{400} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{(x/400)(1-(x/400))}{400}}
$$

In many textbooks, you'll see a section called something like "Confidence interval for a proportion" that covers this.

Comment: Yes I think I see, so in this case $i\rightarrow j$ is considered a success and $i\rightarrow $ anywhereelse, a fail. AT the end of the day, these MLE form a stochastic matrix $P$, such that $P_{ij}$ is the probability of moving from $i\rightarrow j$. Then each $P_{ij}$= your CI formula? But by definition $\sum_{i=1..5}P_i=1$, how can one account for this with a CI?

Comment: Not only is $i\to\text{anywhere else}$ a failure, but $\text{anywhere else}\to j$ is a failure and $\text{anywhere else}\to\text{anywhere else}$ is a failure.

Comment: I was deriving a confidence interval for only _one_ $P_{ij}$.  If one considered all of them, then one would have to account for the dependence among them.

Comment: So the above formula could be used for all room combinations (e.g. A-B,B-E,E-D, etc, in total 25) but would not reflect the dependence of these? What would be the method for accounting for dependence between them to calculate a CI?

Comment: I understand that I would need to calculate the variance and covariance from the data as the MLE follow a multivariate normal distribution. But how? I only have one set of observations?

Comment: There are standard ways to do this for the multinomial distribution.  However, there's another complication that I haven't thought through: If one motion is $i\to j$, the the next must be $j\to\text{somewhere else}$.  This is a further constraint on the distribution.

Comment: What terms should I search for to find the standard ways? As for the transitions $i\rightarrow i$ is possible as well as $j\rightarrow j$